# Integrity Violation in Oracle Database

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I am having some strange data errors in my database. I am not able to find out how the following query results can co-exist.

```
SQL> desc errors;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 err_letid                                         NUMBER(20)
 *some other details*


SQL> desc my_letters;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 LET_ID                                    NOT NULL NUMBER(10)
 LET_ISSUEDTO                              NOT NULL NUMBER(10)
```

A letter is issued to people for certain errors. Not all errors are attached to letters.

In the above table, `err_letid` is a foreign key to `let_id` in `my_letters` table'.

Now the problem is

```
SQL> select * from my_letters where let_id = 818
  2  /

    LET_ID LET_ISSUEDTO 
---------- ------------ 
       818      8877554

SQL> select * from errors where err_letid =818
  2  /

no rows selected

SQL> select * from my_letters where let_id not in (select err_letid from errors);

no rows selected
```

How can this happen?

Comment: There's probably a null value for err_letid in the errors table. Try select count(*) from errors where err_letid is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `not in` with subqueries.  The query returns no rows if *any* value in the subquery is `NULL`.

Instead, use `not exists`:

```
select l.*
from my_letters l
where not exists (select 1 from errors e where l.let_id = e.err_letid);
```

It behaves the way that you would expect.